# Make click on list element using Rselenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to do some web scraping around a web page. The web page looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a list and I need to make click on the second element `Consulta por Cuenta Contrato`. I tried next code but is not working:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)
library(xml2)
library(selectr)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
#Code
#start RSelenium
# using RSelenium to start firefox on the selenium server
remDr <- rsDriver(
  port = 4445L,
  browser = "firefox"
)
#remDr$open()
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L,browser = "firefox")
# open a new Tab on Chrome
remDr$open()
#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate("https://nodejs.eeq.com.ec/consultafacturas/proceso/formulario-ingreso")
Sys.sleep(2)
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "mat-radio-3")
webElem$clickElement()
```

I would like to make click so that I get this:

[image]

Is it possible to do this using `RSelenium`? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with you code is that you aren't correctly selecting the radio button. If you inspect the HTML for the website, you'll see that the item does not have the id `mat-radio-3` as you have listed. The id is `mat-radio-3-input`. So the code should look like:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L,browser = "firefox")
# open a new Tab on Chrome
remDr$open()
#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate("https://nodejs.eeq.com.ec/consultafacturas/proceso/formulario-ingreso")
Sys.sleep(2)
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "mat-radio-3-input")
webElem$clickElement()
```

Comment: Oh this solution is not working, I have tested on same page and click is not enabled. Could you please check if we need to make click in other zone as long as it is a circle element? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue at hand might be that the desired element is assigned an id of either `mat-radio-3` or `mat-radio-3-input` at random.

Therefore, an alternative approach might be to select by partial class name matching to `mat-radio-button` and then select the second element from which to call the `clickElement()` method.

```
webElem <- remDr$findElements(using = "class name", "mat-radio-button")
webElem[[2]]$clickElement()
```